# Counting real roots of bivariate polynomial

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, algebra, theorem-proving

For a proof, I'm working with a polynomial $p(x,m)$ and I need to show that: For any $m\in (0,6)$, $p_m(x)\equiv p(x,m)$ has a unique real root in $(0,1/2)$. I find that this is true by using **Reduce** in Mathematica, but I need to understand how to prove it.

Ideally, I'd like to go through the step-by-step process that the Reduce command does, but I haven't been able to understand it (I tried running trace on the Reduce command but the output is impossible for me to understand).

The polynomial $p$ is named "auxpoly" in the code below.

```
P1[x_, m_] := 
 2 (-6 + m) m^8 (-27 + 2 m) - 
  x (-15930 m^7 + 5451 m^8 + 1158 m^9 - 236880 m^6 x + 87728 m^7 x + 
     46144 m^8 x - 1482048 m^5 x^2 + 616128 m^6 x^2 + 
     703888 m^7 x^2 - 4460544 m^4 x^3 + 2058112 m^5 x^3 + 
     6162880 m^6 x^3 - 6414336 m^3 x^4 + 2120192 m^4 x^4 + 
     34435712 m^5 x^4 - 3538944 m^2 x^5 - 5603328 m^3 x^5 + 
     124934656 m^4 x^5 - 16908288 m^2 x^6 + 289193984 m^3 x^6 - 
     12582912 m x^7 + 407371776 m^2 x^7 + 314572800 m x^8 + 
     100663296 x^9)

P2[x_, m_] := -1836 m^7 + 586 m^8 + 52 m^9 + 
  4 x (-11808 m^6 + 4200 m^7 + 1528 m^8 - 103752 m^5 x + 
     40891 m^6 x + 33098 m^7 x - 398592 m^4 x^2 + 181024 m^5 x^2 + 
     358416 m^6 x^2 - 691200 m^3 x^3 + 303424 m^4 x^3 + 
     2375360 m^5 x^3 - 442368 m^2 x^4 - 319488 m^3 x^4 + 
     10032448 m^4 x^4 - 1720320 m^2 x^5 + 26613760 m^3 x^5 - 
     1572864 m x^6 + 42270720 m^2 x^6 + 36175872 m x^7 + 12582912 x^8)

auxpoly[x_, m_] := (P1[x, m])^2 - 2 x *(m + 2 x)*(P2[x, m]^2)
```

When I run the Reduce command as follows, I find that for each $m$, there is a single real root in the interval $(0,1/2)$. I confirm the result by plotting `CountRoots` for each $m$.

```
Reduce[auxpoly[x, m] == 0 && x > 0 && x <= 1/2 && m > 0 && m < 6, x]
```

[image: Screenshot of output]

Comment: Since you desire a step-by-step solution, why not posting this question on math.stackexchange?

Comment: The code involved uses some heavy machinery such as cylindrical algebraic decomposition (CAD). It will not readily lend itself to human-understandable step-by-step. One can obtain a computer-assisted proof using `Discriminant`, `Roots`, and some related functions, but it is not obvious whether that will suit the needs of s-o-s.

Comment: Thanks @DanielLichtblau, that's helpful!

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

P1[x_, m_] := 
 2 (-6 + m) m^8 (-27 + 2 m) - 
  x (-15930 m^7 + 5451 m^8 + 1158 m^9 - 236880 m^6 x + 87728 m^7 x + 
     46144 m^8 x - 1482048 m^5 x^2 + 616128 m^6 x^2 + 703888 m^7 x^2 - 
     4460544 m^4 x^3 + 2058112 m^5 x^3 + 6162880 m^6 x^3 - 6414336 m^3 x^4 + 
     2120192 m^4 x^4 + 34435712 m^5 x^4 - 3538944 m^2 x^5 - 5603328 m^3 x^5 + 
     124934656 m^4 x^5 - 16908288 m^2 x^6 + 289193984 m^3 x^6 - 
     12582912 m x^7 + 407371776 m^2 x^7 + 314572800 m x^8 + 100663296 x^9)

P2[x_, m_] := -1836 m^7 + 586 m^8 + 52 m^9 + 
  4 x (-11808 m^6 + 4200 m^7 + 1528 m^8 - 103752 m^5 x + 40891 m^6 x + 
     33098 m^7 x - 398592 m^4 x^2 + 181024 m^5 x^2 + 358416 m^6 x^2 - 
     691200 m^3 x^3 + 303424 m^4 x^3 + 2375360 m^5 x^3 - 442368 m^2 x^4 - 
     319488 m^3 x^4 + 10032448 m^4 x^4 - 1720320 m^2 x^5 + 26613760 m^3 x^5 - 
     1572864 m x^6 + 42270720 m^2 x^6 + 36175872 m x^7 + 12582912 x^8)

auxpoly[x_, m_] := (P1[x, m])^2 - 2 x*(m + 2 x)*(P2[x, m]^2)
```

There are four real roots for `0 <= m <= 6`

```
sol = Solve[{auxpoly[x, m] == 0, 0 <= m <= 6}, x, Reals];

Length@sol

(* 4 *)
```

However, only one of these roots is in the interval `0 <= x <= 1/2`

```
sol2 = Solve[{auxpoly[x, m] == 0, 0 <= m <= 6, 0 <= x <= 1/2}, x, Reals];

Length@sol2

(* 1 *)
```

The maximum value of `x` is

```
max = NMaximize[{Normal[x /. sol2[[1]]], 0 < m < 6}, m]

(* {0.161383, {m -> 0.493441}} *)
```

Plotting the root as a function of `m`

```
Plot[x /. sol2, {m, 0, 6}, Epilog ->
  {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[{max[[2, 1, -1]], max[[1]]}]},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {m, x})]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, Bob!
Do you know if it's possible to get the step-by-step process that the Solve command performs to get this result? That would be super helpful.

Comment: For **very simple** problems (not the one that you have) you can use `WolframAlpha`, e.g., `WolframAlpha["solve x^3+x^2+1==0 over reals", {{"ResultOverTheReals", 2}, "Content"}, PodStates -> {"ResultOverTheReals__Step-by-step solution"}]`. However, these are not the steps used by `Solve`.